# gnu make: filter-out escaped whitespace separated words

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following example makefile:

```
EXTRA_OVERRIDES := $(filter-out GIT_VERSION=% BUILD_TARGET=% BUILD_FLAGS=%,$(MAKEOVERRIDES))

$(info MAKEOVERRIDES: $(MAKEOVERRIDES))
$(info EXTRA_OVERRIDES: $(EXTRA_OVERRIDES))

all:
    @touch /dev/null
```

The idea is to filter out "known" `MAKEOVERRIDES`, leaving just the rest.

This works for overrides which consist of a single value:

**example:** *single value known overrides, `BUILD_TARGET`, `GIT_VERSION`*

```
$ make EXTRA_FLAG=1 BUILD_TARGET=foo GIT_VERSION=a298bde
MAKEOVERRIDES: GIT_VERSION=a298bde BUILD_TARGET=foo EXTRA_FLAG=1
EXTRA_OVERRIDES: EXTRA_FLAG=1
```

Where it doesn't work is when passing multiple values in a single override

**example:** *passing multiple values for the `BUILD_FLAGS` override*

```
$ make BUILD_FLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Werror" EXTRA_FLAG=1 BUILD_TARGET=foo GIT_VERSION=a298bde
MAKEOVERRIDES: GIT_VERSION=a298bde BUILD_TARGET=foo EXTRA_FLAG=1 BUILD_FLAGS=-Wall\ -Wextra\ -Werror
EXTRA_OVERRIDES: EXTRA_FLAG=1 -Wextra\ -Werror
```

So even though I pass `BUILD_FLAGS` as a quoted list, and even though `MAKEOVERRIDES` shows `BUILD_FLAGS` having its whitespace escaped, `filter-out` doesn't respect the escaping.

ie:

- `BUILD_FLAGS=-Wall\ -Wextra\ -Werror`: `filter-out BUILD_FLAGS=%` matches `BUILD_FLAGS=-Wall` instead of continuing past the escaped whitespace.

**Question:**

How can I get `filter-out` to include the escaped whitespace in its match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I've found a work-around - namely to preprocess `MAKEOVERRIDES` using `sed`, and then run the `filter-out` on the result.

I can't help but think there must be a better way to achieve this, using make functionality only, but I guess this will work for my particular use-case

```
QUOTED_OVERRIDES:= $(shell echo "$(MAKEOVERRIDES)" | sed 's|\\ |\\|g')
EXTRA_OVERRIDES := $(filter-out GIT_VERSION=% BUILD_TARGET=% BUILD_FLAGS=%,$(QUOTED_OVERRIDES))

$(info MAKEOVERRIDES   : $(MAKEOVERRIDES))
$(info QUOTED_OVERRIDES: $(QUOTED_OVERRIDES))
$(info EXTRA_OVERRIDES : $(EXTRA_OVERRIDES))

all:
    @touch /dev/null
```

**example:**

```
$ make BUILD_FLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Werror" EXTRA_FLAG=1 BUILD_TARGET=foo
MAKEOVERRIDES   : BUILD_TARGET=foo EXTRA_FLAG=1 BUILD_FLAGS=-Wall\ -Wextra\ -Werror
QUOTED_OVERRIDES: BUILD_TARGET=foo EXTRA_FLAG=1 BUILD_FLAGS=-Wall\-Wextra\-Werror
EXTRA_OVERRIDES : EXTRA_FLAG=1
```